# how to write Invitehandler for iOS 9 Xcode 7 beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to develop a simple multiplayer game. As instructed in the Apple doc I am implementing the invite handler "matchforinvite" so that I could accept invite from other players. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchmaker_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKMatchmaker/matchForInvite:completionHandler:

I am doing this via the following function

```
func setUpInviteHandler() {

    GKMatchmaker.sharedMatchmaker().matchForInvite(invite: GKInvite, completionHandler: { match, error -> Void in
        if invite.playerAttributes != 0 {
            print(invite.playerAttributes)
        }
    })

}
```

however, no matter how i change it there is always error from Xcode. How could I fix it?

The problem here (i guess) is that the GKInvite object never exist until there is an invite. However, when you do a function like this, the GKInvite thing has to be initialized in order to be called. How could you initialize a runtime object? The worst is i cannot do !(GKInvite) or GKInvite == nil checking because of the class type. Can anyone help?

Comment: Well, you are quite a bit off. You **have** to possess a valid GKInvite at the point where you want to call `matchForInvite`. You should probably read through some tutorials on that topic. In general `GKInvite` is the type, what you need here is an instance that you normally get from some other callback methods in the match making process.

Comment: thanks for the direction. I will try again. Thank you